# R: return row and column numbers of matches in a data frame

Tags: r, search, indexing

`emperor <- rbind(cbind('Augustus','Tiberius'),cbind('Caligula','Claudius'))`

How do I return the row and column numbers of all the cells that contain the sequence 'us', i.e. [1,1], [1,2], [2,2]?

Comment: Try `which(matrix(grepl('us', emperor), ncol=2), arr.ind=TRUE)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `grepl` to get a `vector` of logical index, convert to a `matrix` of the same dimension as the original `matrix` ('emperor') and wrap with `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`.

```
which(matrix(grepl('us', emperor), ncol=ncol(emperor)), arr.ind=TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   1   1
#[2,]   1   2
#[3,]   2   2
```

Or another way to convert the `grepl` output is by assigning the `dim` to that of the `dim` of 'emperor' and wrap with `which`.

```
 which(`dim<-`(grepl('us', emperor), dim(emperor)), arr.ind=TRUE)
```