# Using Apply functions instead of for loops

Tags: r, apply

I have a data set which consists of 59 columns
columns 4 to 59 contain a mixture of email addresses and nonsense
I want to create a vector (which will eventually go into a data frame) that picks up the unique email addresses from columns 4:59. Below is my function which works very well for one column EMAIL0. The columns are sequential so EMAIL0-EMAIL55

```
udf.Unique.Emails <- function (strcol, data)
{
 vector <- as.character()
 # For All columns with an email in the data set
 for(i in 1:length(data))
 {
 # Check All the items in the row per email
 if (grepl("@", strcol[i]))
   {
    vector <- unique(c(vector,strcol[i]))
   } 
 }
 return (vector)
}

test <- udf.Unique.Emails (foo$EMAIL0, foo.data)
```

I wish to implement this on all columns from 4:59 to produce a single column, can anyone point me in the right direction using the apply family?

Thank you for your time

**#######UPDATE#####**

Due to the sensitivity of the data in Question I cant give too much detail. Below is a mock up where the data is called foo.data and the data and the column are fed into the function

For EMAIL0, foo@fpo.com would be returned from the function

The end result would be a single column with all the unique emails from all the other email columns below

```
$ EMAIL0    (chr) "foo@fpo.com", "Recieved Report", "Daily", "Query", "Weekly", "Products", "Products2", "Results", "Products...
$ EMAIL1    (chr) "foo2@fpo2.com", "", "Nonsense", "", "", "garbage", "", "", "Trace Stack", "", "", "", "", "", "", "JS@fpo.com", "", "",...
$ EMAIL2    (chr) "John.Smith@fpo.com", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "John.Smith.Weston@fpo.com"
```

Comment: Please show us some sample data, along with types of your function input parameters (e.g. list, data frame, etc.).

Comment: You could do something like: `data[which(matrix(grepl("@",as.matrix(data)),ncol=55),arr.ind=T)]`, it gets the indices where there is an `@` in your data and returns the value at these indices (you need to run in only on the subset of data that has the 55 columns you are interested in).

Comment: Actually [this previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003929/r-return-row-and-column-numbers-of-matches-in-a-data-frame) does that.

Comment: Hi @NicE, perfect and far more elegant than my method...Please add it as an answer and thank you very much for your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
data[which(matrix(grepl("@",as.matrix(data)),ncol=55),arr.ind=T)]
```

It will basically get the indices where there is an "@" and returns the value at these indices.

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003929/r-return-row-and-column-numbers-of-matches-in-a-data-frame)